# With Github, is it possible to see what a file looked like at a certain commit, and not just the diff?

Tags: git, github

I know you can use `git show` with the command line to do this, but is there a way with Github to go to a specific commit and see what a file looked like there? I seem to only be able to find diffs between that commit and the previous one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are viewing the commit (either in the "Commits" list of a repo or in a detailed commit view, which shows the diff), you can click "Browse Code" on the right side (below or above the commit SHA).

When in a Compare view or a pull requests's "Files changed" view, you can click "View file @ " on the top right of each file, to view that file at the specified revision.

In general, you can use

```
https://github.com/<USER>/<REPO>/tree/<COMMIT SHA>/relative/path/in/repo
```

to view a tree (i.e. any folder in the repo at that revision) or

```
https://github.com/<USER>/<REPO>/blob/<COMMIT SHA>/relative/path/to/file
```

to view a file at a certain revision.

Answer (score 3):

yes.You can.In the setting option click on show file.

Answer (score 2):

From the commit page, click on “Browse code” (the button is in the light blue section at the top of the commit page). This will take you to the source tree as it was at that point.